# Deploying meanjs to Bluemix, but always failing

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, meanjs

> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>          sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: not found
>          npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
>          npm ERR! argv "node" "/tmp/staged/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
>          npm ERR! node v0.10.40
>          npm ERR! npm  v3.3.5
>          npm ERR! file sh
>          npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>          npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>          npm ERR! syscall spawn
>          npm ERR! v8-debug@0.4.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
>          npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
>          npm ERR! 
>          npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.4.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
>          npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
>          npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>          npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>          npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>          npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>          npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
>          npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>          npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support

Answer (score 1):

To deploy meanjs in Bluemix simply follow the steps Ryan Baxter described in his [article](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/09/02/mean-app-to-bluemix-in-one-click/) and I am summarizing here:

```
$ cf login -a api.ng.bluemix.net
$ cf create-service mongolab sandbox mean-mongo
$ git clone https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git && cd mean
$ npm install
$ grunt build
$ cf push
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Alex's answer above, if you need the ability to debug more than just logs or if you want to use utilities like node-inspector or if you want to just shell into your Bluemix container, then I suggest you take a look at App Management feature in Bluemix.  It takes advantage of the following 4 utilities:

- **devconsole** (development console)
- **shell** (tty.js)
- **inspector** (node-inspector)
- **hc** (Health Center)

For further details, take a look at the blog and video posted below:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/10/05/advanced-debugging-node-apps-bluemix/