# Deployment build issues

Tags: javascript, deployment, ibm-cloud, meanjs

Attempting to deploy a MEANJS to Cloud Foundry with Bluemix. The build keeps failing and I can't figure out how to resolve the dependencies. Any suggestions?

Here is the console log:

Starting app mean in org ...

```
-----> Downloaded app package (86M)
-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (43M)

-----> IBM SDK for Node.js Buildpack v3.7-20160826-1101
       Based on Cloud Foundry Node.js Buildpack v1.5.18
-----> Creating runtime environment
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_ENV=cloud-foundry
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       npm scripts will see NODE_ENV=production (not 'cloud-foundry')
       https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#production
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  >=0.12.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   >=2.0.0
       Resolving node version >=0.12.0 via 'node-version-resolver'
       Installing IBM SDK for Node.js (4.5.0) from cache
       Resolving npm version >=2.0.0 via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing npm 3.10.7 (replacing version 2.15.9)...
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules (exists - skipping)
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Checking and configuring service extensions before installing dependencies
-----> Building dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       > v8-debug@0.7.7 preinstall /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/v8-debug
       > node -e 'process.exit(0)'
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: not found
       npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-33-generic
       npm ERR! file sh
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
       npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.7.7 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
       npm ERR! argv "/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild" "--nodedir=/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node"
       npm ERR! errno ENOENT
       npm ERR! syscall spawn
       npm ERR! v8-debug@0.7.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR!
       npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
       npm ERR! not with npm itself.
       npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       npm ERR!     npm bugs v8-debug
       npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
       npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
       npm ERR! node v4.5.0
       npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
       npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
       npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
       npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
       npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
       npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/staged/app/npm-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       Some possible problems:
       - node_modules checked into source control
       http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html
       - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
       docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed


FAILED
Error restarting application: BuildpackCompileFailed

TIP: use 'cf logs mean --recent' for more information
```

Comment: There is a MEAN sample for Bluemix at https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/nodejs-MEAN-stack

Comment: This also seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981441/deploying-meanjs-to-bluemix-but-always-failing